# Import module from a different folder Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I am working on python 2.7 and I have 2 files:

test.py:

```
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import Controller, RemoteController, OVSController
from mininet.node import CPULimitedHost, Host, Node
from mininet.node import OVSKernelSwitch, UserSwitch
from mininet.node import IVSSwitch
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mininet.link import TCLink, Intf
from subprocess import call
```

This is the list of modules that I have to import from the mininet sub folder of the mininet folder in the `test.py` file.

This the list of the module that I have to import in the `main.py` file under the `net_test` folder:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/mininet/mininet')

from mininet.mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.mininet.node import Controller, RemoteController, OVSController, CPULimitedHost, Host, Node, OVSKernelSwitch, UserSwitch, IVSSwitch
from mininet.mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mininet.mininet.link import TCLink, Intf
```

For the `test.py` file everything works, but I have tried to import using the sys for the `main.py` but is saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Create_topology import Create_Topology
  File "/home/mininet/net_test/Create_topology.py", line 7, in <module>
    from mininet.mininet.net import Mininet
ImportError: No module named mininet.net
```

This is the file structure:

[image]

This is the file structure of the mininet folder:

[image]

This is the file structure of the mininet subfoder (inside of the mininet folder):

[image]

I know, it is a bit confusing, but the name of the machine is actually mininet.

As you can see in the following image the folder already has an `__init__.py`:

[image]

Do you have any idea how should I solve it?

Comment: maybe add an empty file `mininet/mininet/__init__.py` ? this would be at the same level as `net.py`

Comment: @jkr oh, I am so sorry, but that file already exists

Comment: in that case, you should edit your question with the true file structure.

Comment: @jkr ok, give me 1 minute

Comment: @jkr Yes, ready !

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
from application.app.folder.file import func_name
```

Just make sure the folder also contains an `__init__.py`.
This allows it to be included as a package.
I am not sure why the other answers talk about PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, please look again to the question.